# Prove the following trig inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Show that $$\frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{3}{25}< \arctan \frac{4}{3} < \frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{1}{6}$$
I tried using some inequalities I know like $\ln(1+x) < \arctan(x) < \arcsin(x)$ on $0<x<1$. I also drew some triangles. Other than that I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: I tried using some inequalities I know like $\ln(1+x) < \arctan(x) < \arcsin(x)$ on $0<x<1$. I also drew some triangles. Other than that kind of stuck. I'll add this comment to the original post. I guess that's what's pissing people off.

Comment: It's just the mean value theorem.

Comment: Don't we have a formula for $\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)$? Maybe it says something, with $x=4/3$ and $y=1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Duh… I always forget to apply that to inequalities, thanks! I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Daniel Fisher** suggests using the **mean** [value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). But I hate mean things, and since no *nice* value theorem is known to exist, I'm afraid we'll just have to use one of those simple [trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) instead. We know that $\tan\dfrac\pi4=1$, and that $\tan(a+b)=\dfrac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\cdot\tan b}$ , so by taking the tangent of all three sides, we have $\dfrac{1+\tan\frac3{25}}{1-\tan\frac3{25}}<\dfrac43<\dfrac{1+\tan\frac16}{1-\tan\frac16}\iff\tan\frac3{25}<\dfrac17<\tan\frac16$ Now, given that the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) expansion of the the tangent function is $\tan x\simeq x+O(x^3)$, and that in both cases *x* is small enough to make the presence of its higher powers irrelevant, this boils down to proving that $\dfrac3{25}<\dfrac17<\dfrac16$ , which is trivial.